# find the number of pairs that belong to a column but not a higher order column

Tags: python, algorithm, set, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I have an `n x k` binary numpy array, I am trying to find an efficient way to find the number of *pairs* of ones that belong to some `column[j]` but not to any higher column, in this case higher means in increasing index value.

For example in the array:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

the output should be `array([ 0,  0, 11,  2, 14,  1], dtype=int32)`. This makes sense because we see `column[2]` has all ones, so any pair of ones will necessarily have a highest column in common of at least 2, because even though `column[0]` also has all ones, it's lower, so no pair of ones have it as their highest in common. In all cases I am considering, `column[0]` will always have all ones.

Here is some example code that works and I believe is something like O(n^2 k)

```
def hcc(i, j, k, bin_mat):

    # hcc means highest common columns

    # i: index i
    # j: index j
    # k: number of columns - 1
    # bin_mat: binary matrix
    for q in range(k, 0, -1):
        if (bin_mat[i, q] and bin_mat[j, q]):
            return q
    return 0

def get_num_pairs_columns(bin_mat):
    k = bin_mat.shape[1]-1
    num_pairs_hcc = np.zeros(k+1, dtype=np.int32)  # number of one-pairs in columns

    for i in range(bin_mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(bin_mat.shape[0]):
            if(i < j):
                num_pairs_hcc[hcc(i, j, k, bin_mat)] += 1
    return num_pairs_highest_column
```

Another way I've though of approaching the problem is through sets. So every column gets its own set, and the index of every row with a one gets added to such a set. So for the example above, this would look like:

```
set = [{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
 {0, 3, 6, 7},
 {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
 {1, 3, 6},
 {0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7},
 {4, 5}]
```

The idea is to find the number of pairs in `set[j]` that are in no higher set (it can be in a lower set, just not higher). Since, I mentioned before, all cases will have column zero with all ones, every set is a subset of `set[0]`. So a much worse performing code using this approach looks like this:

```
def generate_sets(bin_mat):
    sets = []
    for j in range(bin_mat.shape[1]):
        column = set()
        for i in range(bin_mat.shape[0]):
            if bin_mat[i, j] == 1:
                column.add(i)
        sets.append(column)
    return sets

def get_hcc_sets(bin_mat):
    sets = generate_sets(bin_mat)
    pairs_sets = []
    num_pairs_hcc = np.zeros(len(sets), dtype=np.int32)
    for subset in sets:
        pairs_sets.append({p for p in itertools.combinations(sorted(subset), r = 2)})
    for j in range(len(sets)-1):
        intersections = [pairs_sets[j].intersection(pairs_sets[q]) for q in range(j+1, len(sets))]
        num_pairs_hcc[j] = len(pairs_sets[j] - set.union(*intersections))
    num_pairs_hcc[len(sets)-1]=len(pairs_sets[len(sets)-1])
    return num_pairs_hcc
```

I haven't checked that this sets implementation *always* produces the same results as the previous one, but in the finitely many cases I tried, it works. However, I am 100% certain that my first implementation gives exactly the result I need.

another reference example:

input:

```
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1]], dtype=int32)
```

output:

```
array([16,  6,  6], dtype=int32)
```

Is there a way to beat my O(n^2 k) implementation. It seems rather brute force and like there should be something I can exploit to make this calculation faster. I always expect `n` to be greater than `k`, by a orders of magnitude in many cases. So I'd rather the `k` have a higher exponent than the `n`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going for the `O(n² k)` approach in python, you can do it with much shorter code using `itertools` and `set`; the code might be more efficient too.

```py
import itertools

t = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
     [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
     [1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
n,k = len(t),len(t[0])

# build set of pairs of 1 in column j
def candidates(j):
  return {(i1, i2) for (i1, i2) in itertools.combinations(range(n), 2) if 1 == t[i1][j] == t[i2][j]}

# build set of pairs of 1 in higher columns
def badpairs(j):
  return {(i1, i2) for (i1, i2) in itertools.combinations(range(n), 2) if any(1 == t[i1][j0] == t[i2][j0] for j0 in range(j+1, k))}

# set difference
def finalpairs(j):
  return candidates(j) - badpairs(j)

# print pairs
for j in range(k):
  print(j, finalpairs(j))

# 0 set()
# 1 set()
# 2 {(2, 4), (1, 2), (2, 7), (4, 6), (0, 6), (2, 3), (6, 7), (0, 2), (2, 6), (5, 6), (2, 5)}
# 3 {(1, 6), (3, 6)}
# 4 {(0, 1), (0, 7), (0, 4), (3, 4), (1, 5), (3, 7), (0, 3), (1, 4), (5, 7), (1, 7), (0, 5), (1, 3), (4, 7), (3, 5)}
# 5 {(4, 5)}

# print number of pairs
for j in range(k):
  print(j, len(finalpairs(j)))

# 0 0
# 1 0
# 2 11
# 3 2
# 4 14
# 5 1
```

Alternate definition for `badpairs`:

```py
def badpairs(j):
  return set().union(*(candidates(j0) for j0 in range(j+1, k)))
```

**Slightly different approach: avoid building `badpairs`**

```py
def finalpairs(j):
  return {(i1, i2) for (i1, i2) in itertools.combinations(range(n), 2) if 1 == t[i1][j] == t[i2][j] and not any(1 == t[i1][j0] == t[i2][j0] for j0 in range(j+1, k))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the perspective. This is definitely better than my sets approach, but still slower than my brute force (although much prettier for sure). I was thinking of maybe using the inclusion-exclusion principle and storing all the set intersections so I don't have to re-calculate them every time, I'm not sure if would be better. The formula I'd be implementing would be ```|A'_i| - |U A'_i n A'_j| j=0 to j=k-1``` where A' is the set of pairs. I don't think I really need the set of pairs though, I should get away knowing just the sizes of the set of pairs which would be ```{A_i choose 2}```.

Comment: @tinman248 I've updated my answer with a slightly more optimized code (at the end of the answer). It avoids building all of `badpairs`, so it should be much more efficient on some inputs; but in the worst-case it's still O(n² k).